# Non-ASCII identifiers for python 2.7

Tags: python

I know that in python 3.x I can use Non-ASCII identifiers (PEP 3131).

```
x1 = 2
x2 = 4
Δx = x2 - x1
print(Δx)
```

Is there such feature in python 2.7? Maybe, has anybody ported it to 2.x branch?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Just use `dx`.

Comment: I dont have an answer for you but please dont do this ... just call it delta_x

Comment: @dx: it's simply example. In real formule expression will be like this: Δδj = ϰ * Áj * Δȳ For me it will be clearer..

Comment: @AntonBarycheuski That is in no way clearer. Imagine someone coming across your code trying to 1) read it and 2) edit it. It is very difficult to type those characters. Please just use some other name, like dx or delta_x.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: For extra credit, try and guess how many people made [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))-related jokes around the time of PEP 3131, then check the mailing list archives to see how close you came. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in Python 2; names are constricted to using ASCII letters and digits only.

See the [Identifiers and Keywords](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) section of the reference manual:

> Identifiers (also referred to as names) are described by the following
>   lexical definitions:
>
> ```
> identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
> letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
> lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
> uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
> digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
> ```

It was [PEP 3131](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/) that expanded the range of possible characters for Python 3.

There is little point in porting this to the 2.x branch; it would remain a niche 'feature' that requires everyone running your code to install a specially patched and compiled interpreter.

Note that the change is not trivial; Python 2 identifiers are byte strings, *not* unicode values. You'd have to find *all* locations in the interpreter that handle identifiers and verify that these can handle non-ASCII values or retool these for unicode strings instead. This goes way beyond the compiler!

Comment: Plus, no new features will _ever_ be ported to Python 2.x, unless there's a huge change in the mindset of the python dev community, so even if none of this were true, the chance of it happening would be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I mean, *technically* this is what you asked for:

```
>>> x1 = 2
>>> x2 = 4
>>> locals()[u'Δx'] = x2 - x1
>>> print locals()[u'Δx']
2
```